# How to upload multiple images to facebook from iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

i want to upload Multiple images to Facebook from iphone. And i have search so many things and made a code as below: but it's not working. Any help will be appreciated.

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSString *jsonRequest1 = @"{ \"method\": \"POST\", \"relative_url\": \"me/photos\" , \"body\": \"Hello 1\", \"attached_files\": \"file1\" }";

NSString *jsonRequest2 = @"{ \"method\": \"POST\", \"relative_url\": \"me/photos\" , \"body\": \"Hello 2\", \"attached_files\": \"file2\" }";

NSString *jsonRequestsArray = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[ %@, %@ ]", jsonRequest1, jsonRequest2];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:jsonRequestsArray,@"batch",nil];

NSString *url1=@"http://uhallnyu.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/green-apple.jpg";

NSString *url2=@"http://scm-l3.technorati.com/12/04/24/67277/apple.gif?t=20120424140104";

NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url1]];

UIImage *img1  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data1];

NSData *data2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url2]];

UIImage *img2  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data2];

[params setObject:img1 forKey:@"file1"];

[params setObject:img2 forKey:@"file2"];

[[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can upload photos to  facebook using :-
You can have a switch case to read the type of image from your image file and get imagedata using functions  UIImagePNGRepresentation,UIImageJPEGRepresentation,etc.

```
NSData *yourImageData= UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);
```

Initialize the dictionary :-

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDictWithParam= [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Your text", @"message", yourImageWithData, @"theSource", nil];
```

finally send post :-

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/photos" andParams:mutableDictWithParam andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

You can have it in loop to send more than one image.

Comment: i want to post Multiple images. i have successfully uploaded single image to Facebook. but i am getting prob in uploading multiple photos.

Comment: Sending images with loop one by one may cause temporary suspension of Facebook account. As FB may treat as spam posting